# HttpWebRequest Issues on file upload

Tags: c#, silverlight-2.0

The following code is not working..

The WriteCallback never happens and checking fiddler and also

it never POST but does a GET

> private void Upload() {
>       var ub = new UriBuilder(UploadUrl);
>       Debug.Text += "Requesting " + ub.Uri + "\n";
>       var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ub.Uri);
>       webrequest.Method = "POST";
>       Debug.Text += "Method : " + webrequest.Method + "\n";
>       webrequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new
>   AsyncCallback(WriteCallback),
>   webrequest);
>       Debug.Text += "webRequested\n";
>  }
>
> private void
>   WriteCallback(IAsyncResult
>   asynchronousResult) 
> {
>       Debug.Text += "WriteCallback\n";
>  }

gives me the : 
Requesting http://localhost:22792/receiver.ashx?filename=Unsaved (1).AVI&StartByte=0&Complete=False
Method : POST
webRequested

Comment: Why don't you simply use `WebClient`?

Comment: because it is simply easier to write a WeRequest to upload data Using silverlight

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code in `WriteCallback` to indicate that you're done processing the event.  So, I'm assuming your `Main` function or thread is not waiting for the request to be completed.  Please see the sample code in the following documentation:

- [WebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx)

In particular, look at the C# example and search for `allDone` which is a `ManualResetEvent` used by the `Main` method to wait until the callback signals completion.